# Linking PyQt output with python file

Tags: python, pyqt

How do I link this PyQt output with the python file at the bottom?I looked at various tutorials but I can not figure it out. How do I set values to the radio buttons so if someone clicks earth r is filled in with 6.4*10**6 and g is set to 9.8?

### from Qt designer

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from projectile_ui import Ui_Form


class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(443, 340)
        self.Tilte = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.Tilte.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 10, 131, 16))
        self.Tilte.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Tilte"))
        self.Vo = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(Form)
        self.Vo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 81, 22))
        self.Vo.setMaximum(999999999.0)
        self.Vo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Vo"))
        self.angle = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(Form)
        self.angle.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 81, 22))
        self.angle.setMaximum(90.0)
        self.angle.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("angle"))
        self.dt = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(Form)
        self.dt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 81, 22))
        self.dt.setDecimals(3)
        self.dt.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dt.setMaximum(1.0)
        self.dt.setSingleStep(0.001)
        self.dt.setProperty("value", 0.01)
        self.dt.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dt"))
        self.Jupiter = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Jupiter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 82, 17))
        self.Jupiter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Jupiter"))
        self.Saturn = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Saturn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 82, 17))
        self.Saturn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Saturn"))
        self.Sun = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Sun.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 82, 17))
        self.Sun.setCheckable(True)
        self.Sun.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Sun"))
        self.Venus = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Venus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 82, 17))
        self.Venus.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Venus"))
        self.Mars = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Mars.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 82, 17))
        self.Mars.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Mars"))
        self.Neptune = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Neptune.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 82, 17))
        self.Neptune.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Neptune"))
        self.Earth = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Earth.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 200, 82, 17))
        self.Earth.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Earth"))
        self.Uranus = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Uranus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 82, 17))
        self.Uranus.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Uranus"))
        self.Mercury = QtGui.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.Mercury.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 82, 17))
        self.Mercury.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Mercury"))
        self.Vo_Label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.Vo_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 40, 71, 21))
        self.Vo_Label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Vo_Label"))
        self.Angle_Label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.Angle_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 61, 21))
        self.Angle_Label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Angle_Label"))
        self.dt_Label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.dt_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 61, 21))
        self.dt_Label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dt_Label"))
        self.LCDheight = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.LCDheight.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 150, 181, 71))
        self.LCDheight.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("LCDheight"))
        self.lcdTotaltime = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdTotaltime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 250, 181, 71))
        self.lcdTotaltime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdTotaltime"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 132, 181, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 232, 181, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 181, 61))
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setDefault(False)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Tilte.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Projectile Motion Calculator", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Jupiter.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Jupiter", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Saturn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Saturn", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Sun.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Sun ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Venus.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Venus", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Mars.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Mars", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Neptune.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Neptune", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Earth.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Earth", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Uranus.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Uranus", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Mercury.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Mercury", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Vo_Label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Initial Velocity ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Angle_Label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Angle", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dt_Label.setToolTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Smaller number gives more accurate results.</p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dt_Label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Time Step", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Max Height ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Total Time ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Calculate", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Code I want to link to the UI.

```
from math import*
def main():
    loopiterations = int()

    dt = eval(input("")) ##time step

    Vo = eval(input(""))
    xo = 0
    yo = 0
    angle = eval(input(""))
    angle = angle * (pi / 180)
    Vox = Vo * cos(angle)
    Voy = Vo * sin(angle)
    y =  (yo + Voy * dt)
    r=eval(input(""))  ## r= 6.4*10**6 for earth 
    g = eval(input(""))  ## m/s **2
    Vy=Voy - g * dt
    iterations = 0

    while not (Vy < 0):
        y =  (yo + Voy * dt)
        Vy= (Voy - g * dt)
        x = (xo + Vox * dt)
        Vx = Vox
        iterations = iterations + 1
        yo = y
        xo = x
        Vox = Vx
        Voy = Vy
    print (y)
    print(iterations)
```

Comment: You are going to need to get rid of those `eval(input)` calls to use this code in your UI. It needs to be split up from view and business logic

Answer (score 1):

If you designed that UI in QtDesigner and still have the .ui file kicking around, the easy way to work with it is to actually not bother with the pyuic, and just use it directly:

```
from PyQt4 import uic

...
class ProjectileObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProjectileObject, self).__init__()
        self.ui = None
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('projectile.ui', self.ui)
        self.ui.Saturn.clicked.connect(self.radioClicked)    #These lines connect your
        self.ui.Uranus.clicked.connect(self.radioClicked)    #interface to your code
        ...                                                  #you can look up other signals as well
        self.ui.show()
    def radioClicked():
        #This code can inspect the various radio buttons, and take different actions
        #depending on which one was clicked
```

Note that it is much more efficient to use the action editor in QtDesigner to create a "switchPlanet" action, then connect all of your radio buttons to that action in QtDesigner using the Signal/Slot editor, then you just do something like `self.ui.switchPlanet.triggered.connect(self.radioClicked)` in your code and you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

First, to address your radio buttons, I would put them into a [QButtonGroup](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qbuttongroup.html) in code. It will consolidate all those buttons into a single point of contact, with the ability to make them exclusive:

```
self.planetGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
self.planetGroup.setExclusive(True)
self.planetGroup.addButton(self.Saturn)
self.planetGroup.addButton(self.Uranus)

self.planetGroup.buttonClicked["QAbstractButton*"].connect(self.planetChanged)

self.planetChanged(self, planetButton):
    if planetButton == self.Saturn:
        # do something
    elif planetButton == self.Uranus:
        # do something
```

You could even make it easier by using a dict containing the wired values for each button:

```
self._planetVals = {
    self.Saturn: "saturn",
    self.Uranus: "uranus",
}

self.planetChanged(self, planetButton):
    do_stuff_with(self._planetVals[planetButton])
```

Now for the issue with your `main` code. It needs to be split from its dependency on gathering user input with `input`, and its business logic:

```
from math import *

def main():
    dt = eval(input("")) ##time step
    Vo = eval(input(""))
    angle = eval(input(""))
    r=eval(input(""))  ## r= 6.4*10**6 for earth 
    g = eval(input(""))  ## m/s **2

    print process(dt, Vo, angle, r, g)

def process(dt, Vo, angle, r, g):
    loopiterations = 0

    xo = 0
    yo = 0
    angle = angle * (pi / 180)
    Vox = Vo * cos(angle)
    Voy = Vo * sin(angle)
    y =  (yo + Voy * dt)
    Vy=Voy - g * dt
    iterations = 0

    while not (Vy < 0):
        y =  (yo + Voy * dt)
        Vy= (Voy - g * dt)
        x = (xo + Vox * dt)
        Vx = Vox
        iterations = iterations + 1
        yo = y
        xo = x
        Vox = Vx
        Voy = Vy
    # print (y)
    # print(iterations)
    return y, iterations
```

Now you are free to import that module and use the `process` function, by passing it values collected from your UI

The missing piece of this puzzle is to create a main PyQt4 window class that uses your Qt Designer UI, and your generic business logic, to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted, the first thing you need to do is to leave the module generated by `pyuic` as it is: don't edit it.

Instead, you should import it into a separate module where all your main program logic will be. This will allow you to change things in Qt Designer and re-generate the ui module without disturbing the other code.

The script below links together two sections of code in your example. Save it as `projectile.py`, and then re-generate your ui module with `pyuic` and save it as `projectile_ui.py`.

Obviously, you will need to tweak the script a bit to get things working the way you want, but hopefully it will help get you started.

```
from math import*
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from projectile_ui import Ui_Form

constants = {
    'Sun': (0, 0),
    'Mercury': (0, 0),
    'Venus': (0, 0),
    'Earth': (6.4*10**6, 9.81),
    'Mars': (0, 0),
    'Jupiter': (0, 0),
    'Saturn': (0, 0),
    'Uranus': (0, 0),
    'Neptune': (0, 0),
    }

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.radioButtons = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Sun)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Mercury)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Venus)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Earth)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Mars)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Jupiter)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Saturn)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Uranus)
        self.radioButtons.addButton(self.Neptune)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleCalculate)

    def handleCalculate(self):
        loopiterations = int()

        dt = self.dt.value() # time step

        Vo = self.Vo.value()
        xo = 0
        yo = 0
        angle = self.angle.value()
        angle = angle * (pi / 180)
        Vox = Vo * cos(angle)
        Voy = Vo * sin(angle)
        y =  (yo + Voy * dt)

        iterations = y = r = g = 0

        button = self.radioButtons.checkedButton()

        if button is not None:
            # r= 6.4*10**6 for earth, g= m/s **2
            r, g = constants[str(button.objectName())]

            Vy=Voy - g * dt

            if r > 0 and g > 0:

                while not (Vy < 0):
                    y =  (yo + Voy * dt)
                    Vy= (Voy - g * dt)
                    x = (xo + Vox * dt)
                    Vx = Vox
                    iterations = iterations + 1
                    yo = y
                    xo = x
                    Vox = Vx
                    Voy = Vy

        self.LCDheight.display(y)
        self.lcdTotaltime.display(iterations)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```